# How to call a function from the R mutate function of dplyr to add a calculated column?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am getting stuck on how to add a new computed column to a tibble. This is my code, and when it executes, all the rows in the new column (`scs_oi_pre`) contain the same values, while the input is different.  I am looking for the mean of `scs_pre_1` and `scs_pre_2` to be calculated row by row.  If I replace `mean(c(scs_pre_1, scs_pre_2)` with `scs_pre_1 + scs_pre_2`, the sum is calculated fine, but using a function is where the issue lies.

```
scsData <- tibble(scs_pre_1, scs_pre_2) %>%
  mutate(scs_oi_pre = mean(c(scs_pre_1, scs_pre_2)))
```

Output

[image]

Could you let me know what I am missing?

Comment: It's helpful if you can post a sample dataset to work with.  Either `dput(df)` or, if it's a big data frame, `dput(head(df))` is good.  Or, as I added in my answer, you can just create toy data to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: Use `rowMeans` : `tibble(scs_pre_1, scs_pre_2) %>% mutate(scs_oi_pre = rowMeans(.))`

Comment: Thanks @ronak-shah, that would have worked too, but my code was a bit more complex than the simple example I gave, and in the end, I needed to use rowwise() to do the calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One `dplyr` idiom is to use `rowwise()` with [`c_across`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html):

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(avg = mean(c_across(c(pre_1, pre_2))))

# A tibble: 10 x 3
# Rowwise: 
     pre_1  pre_2      avg
     <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 -0.560   1.22   0.332  
 2 -0.230   0.360  0.0648 
 3  1.56    0.401  0.980  
 4  0.0705  0.111  0.0906 
 5  0.129  -0.556 -0.213  
 6  1.72    1.79   1.75   
 7  0.461   0.498  0.479  
 8 -1.27   -1.97  -1.62   
 9 -0.687   0.701  0.00725
10 -0.446  -0.473 -0.459
```

Data:

```r
set.seed(123)
df <- tibble(pre_1 = rnorm(10), pre_2 = rnorm(10))
```

Comment: Hi @andrew_reece, rowwise() was exactly what I needed!  I had totally missed that.  Thank you so much for putting me on the right track.